# Meteor redirect on login with Iron Router - layout not changes

Tags: authentication, meteor, iron-router

I have a layout for the login/signup process and a layout for the app itself, `Welcome` and `App` respectively. This is how I try to redirect between them:

```
  this.route('App', {
    path: '/',
    template: 'Home',
    layoutTemplate: 'App',
    onBeforeAction: function(pause) {
      if (!Meteor.user()) {
        this.setLayout('Welcome');
        this.render('Login');
      } else {
        this.setLayout('App');
        this.render('Home');
      }
    }
  });
```

The problem is that only the layout changes, the template remains the same (`home`). Any ideas why?

Bonus question: I tried to do that with URL paths but it is slower and there is content flash. Is there a better way to do the logged-in check?

Comment: Does anything change when you 'return pause()'?

Comment: YES! without the `return` though

Comment: Ok at the very top you are setting the template to home. But never changing it once you determine the layout should be app. I would suggest creating two separate routes.  And have a conditional to check the users before the route is able to process.

Comment: Is this now answered?

Comment: @rwatts I tried, but there is content flash on the check, and It's faster this way

Comment: Does it work calling pause() ? Or is there still a problem :) ?

Comment: Yes it does, someone should write it as an answer (I also would like to know why it solved it)